# passing string as a parameter in print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I want the below output from print statement in which "When was the company founded?" should be  the parameter.
`python3.6 -W ignore bertrun.py "When was the company founded?"`

I tried doing below but it doesn't work

```
x="When was the company founded?"
print("python3.6 -W ignore bertrun.py {}".format(x))
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far to solve your problem. In this case maybe you are just missing a `print` function?

Comment: In contrast with what the title of your question states, there is no `print` statement here!

Comment: `"python3.6 -W ignore bertrun.py {}".format(x)` this creates a new `str` object. You need assign it a variable or print it. Try this `print("python3.6 -W ignore bertrun.py {}".format(x))`

Comment: Sorry I missed the print statement. Edited the post now. @Ch3steR No that doesn't work

Comment: @RishabhJain What's the expected output?

Comment: Expected output -> python3.6 -W ignore bertrun.py "When was the company founded?"

Comment: `print('python3.6 -W ignore bertrun.py "{}"'.format(x))` use this @RishabhJain

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the print statement, use this:

```py
x = "When was the company founded?"
print("python3.6 -W ignore bertrun.py {0}".format(x))
```

```
>>> x = "When was the company founded?"
>>> print("python3.6 -W ignore bertrun.py {0}".format(x))
python3.6 -W ignore bertrun.py When was the company founded?
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the print statement. Edited the post now.  It doesn't work with that.

Comment: @RishabhJain, I edited my post, is that not your expected output?

Comment: Expected output >>> ```python3.6 -W ignore bertrun.py "When was the company founded?"```

Comment: Are you trying to actually execute a script called `betrun.py` from this?

Comment: Yes and I want the statement in that format so that I can pass the whole string as a parameter .

Comment: you should use `os.system`